# Use JavaScript-Class in Script-Tag

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel application with Blade templates and `script` tags.
I try to import a javascript class, but I get the error message:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Script class :

```
 class DummyClass {

    constructor() {
    }

    testValidate(){
        return false;
    }
 }
```

and i need it in the

```
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">

     import DummyClass from "<PATH TO THE MIX-DIST-FOLDER WITH URL>";

      let dummy = new DummyClass()
 

   </script>
@endpush
```

What is the reason and how can I use the class in the script tag?

Comment: The error is literally telling you what's wrong, and you should have clicked through the help link that came with that error: you're using `import` in a script that you didn't load as a module, but as regular globally injected JS, so your script tag needs `type="module"`. (and it does _not_ need `type`, under HTML5 rules scripts tags are for JS, and only need `type` when you're _not_ loading JS)